# i can't get last insert id from database in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to create an id in CodeIgniter like `PTGS-1` where the 1 is from the column with auto increment, and `PTGS` from the function I've created.

I create 2 columns, 1 just for auto increment, and 1 other for custom id `PTGS-1`. and every I've to insert a data, the column with custom id always return `PTGS-0`, it won't get the **last insert id**.

this is my function for custom id in model

```
public function custIdPetugas() {

    $prefix = "PTGS" . "-";
    $lastid = $this->db->insert_id();

    $customid = $prefix.$lastid;

    return $customid;

}
```

and this function in the model to handle user input

```
public function simpan() {

    $custom_id = $this->custIdPetugas();
    $post = $this->input->post();

    $data = array(
        'custom_id' => $custom_id,
        'nama_petugas' => $post['nama'],
        'username' => $post['uname'],
        'password' => password_hash($post['pword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
        'tgl_lahir' => $post['tgllahir'],
        'alamat' => $post['alamat'],
        'no_telpon' => $post['notelpon']
    );

    $this->db->insert($this->tbl, $data);

}
```

and the controller

```
public function tambahPetugas() {

    $petugas = $this->PetugasModel;
    $validation = $this->form_validation;
    $validation->set_rules($petugas->rules());

    if($validation->run()) {

        $petugas->simpan();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('berhasil', 'Data berhasil ditambah!');

    }

    $this->load->view('petugas/petugas-tambah');

}
```

the problem just with that custom id, I can cleanly insert data from form to database, but the custom id always returns 0.

thanks!

Comment: You can get last insert ID after inserting the record. so put this line of code `$custom_id = $this->custIdPetugas();` after this line `$this->db->insert($this->tbl, $data);`

Comment: i got an error, undefined variable custom_id. because its process, from first line to last line.  so $custom_id = $this->custIdPetugas(); read in last, and declaring custom_id before this can be error

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code for getting last insert ID after inserting the record in the DB.

```
$this->db->insert($this->tbl, $data);
$custom_id = $this->custIdPetugas();
```

But if you want to get before insert the record use this.
Suppose your last insert ID is 99 it will give you 100 in return

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
  FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
  AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';
```

Another way to get last insert ID before inserting the record.

```
$last_id = SELECT MAX(id) FROM table;
```

Increment by value 1 for next record

Model

```
public function custIdPetugas() {

    $prefix = "PTGS" . "-";
    //Suppose last ID is 23 

    $lastid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM table')->row();

    //$lastid = 23; Increment it by one for next unique value
    $customid = $prefix.$lastid->max_id;

    return $customid;

}
```

Comment: where can i put this? SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
  FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
  AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';

Comment: with $this->db->query() ? can u give an example?

Comment: ITS WORK THANKSSS!!!:)). but its possible to +1 at max id? when i try reset the auto increment to 0, and input the first record it will be 'PTGS- ' with no id, after that record, and i input once again, and its work to PTGS-1

Comment: If your first record is with id 0. After getting the id with this code `$lastid = $this->db->query('SELECT MAX(id) as max_id FROM table')->row()` increment id by 1 like this `$new_increment_id = $lastid +1`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in your `insert_id()` function. What you need is to call the latest number from your `custom_id`, then increment it. So, first to call the latest number, I stored it in function called `insert_id`:

```
public function insert_id()
{       
    //here is query for called max id, because u have 4 character before the number so use right instead max. 
    $sql= sprintf("SELECT MAX(RIGHT(custom_id,1)) AS key FROM your_tables_name"); 
    $qry= $this->db->query($sql);
    $row= $qry->row();
    //here is checking if the record is null
    $record= $row->key;
    if ($record== null) {
        $record = 0;
    }
    $record+= 1;

    return $record
}
```